# Google drive incremental sync

Tags: google-drive-api

I found this article regarding incremental sync for calendar: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/sync. Is there similar mechanism for Drive (e.g. I fully synced the data and would like to retrieve all the resources that have been modified since the last sync request)?
Thank you.

Comment: theres an api to get notified of drive changes. you could queue them up in your side.

Comment: I think in this case the easiest way would be to save last sync time stamp and request data with ModifiedTimeStamp > LastSyncTimeStamp next time.

Comment: Similar way to do it would be to use REST API as described here:https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-changes. But in general this is the same way as I suggested before.